# How do I create a ROS topic publisher/subscriber?

Tags: ros, serial, topic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I have a sensor from which I read data via a serial communication (port is of type ttyUSB). Now I am thinking of writing two packages, "publisher_node" and "client". What I want is, publisher_node should read data from the sensor continuously, and publish it as a topic (basically just scream out the values). On the other end, in the client package, I have a specific task, during which I want to poll the device for readings.

I think that using a topic rather than a service is much more logical here. Data flow is a unidirectional stream. Its sort of like filling a cup(client) with water from a river(publisher_node). Am I thinking in the right direction?

**My System:** Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit

**ROS version:** ROS electric

Here are some of the key questions I have:

1. How do I create a topic for publisher_node? Is there any tutorial online for that? Maybe any step by step procedure..?
2. Once I know how to create a topic, I will do that in publisher_node. Then I will 'rosmake' and 'rosrun publisher_node publisher_node'. After that, I will make sure I have the topic up, by doing 'rostopic list'. All is OK. Now how do I write code/make the client "subscribe" to the topic? Any guidelines here?
3. Also, since this is serial communication, I want a special functionality with the topic. I want the user to have an option of setting the frequency of publishing (i.e how fast the data is screamed out). Is this possible with ROS?

**Note:** Yes, I am using a serial device, but I have not used rosserial in any way. I am implementing my own serial port by using the **termios API** in Linux.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38088/how-do-i-create-a-ros-topic-publisher/subscriber?/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2012-07-06**:
Thanks cagatay and Lorenz. The simple publisher/subscriber in the ROS tutorial is what I wanted. I have another question though. It says that spin() keeps on calling all client callback functions till Ctrl+C are pressed or the node is shut down. How can I subscribe at will (and not continuously)?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-06**:
Best if you open a new question for this. I think, it has been asked recently though: http://answers.ros.org/question/37869/subscribing-and-publishing/

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2012-07-06**:
Yep, I will open a new question for this and include what I understood from the tip you just gave me
above. Thanks Lorenz :)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-06**:
Did you find the tutorials hard to locate?

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2012-07-06**:
Hi joq,
No, in fact, to be totally true, I had skimmed over them about a month ago. I just thought that creating a topic, and listening to the messages on that topic would be a much more complex task than what was given in the tutorial. Turns out it isn't! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [ros tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) are always a good starting point. In particular, there are tutorials on how to create a publisher and a subscriber.

For setting the publish frequency, you have a few choices. If it is sufficient to set the rate once, when your node is started up, you can use a ros parameter that is best set using a launch file.

If you need to change the publish rate at run time, you can either use a service or use [dynamic_reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure). While the former one should be easier to implement, I think the latter one is more flexible. For instance, you can use a nice GUI to change the parameters which is really handy when you are trying to find a good value.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

start from here

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber

this is going to help you

here is a serialport implementation in ros & linux , this might help too

[http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~fuzzgun/usbi2c-ros-pkg/trunk/view/head:/src/serialport.cpp](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Efuzzgun/usbi2c-ros-pkg/trunk/view/head:/src/serialport.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1